# Sqlite database doesn't work with my Android application

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an existing Sqlite database that doesn't work with my application. Can anyone know how to help me? Also I've made a little test .db file with just one table and it worked. Think there is something wrong with the big database that I posted picture of but i'm not sure what.

I've posted picture of what the database looks like, if you need anymore screenschoots etc. ask.

http://tinypic.com/r/35arg38/6

Here is the onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView contentLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_log);

        // Create the database
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(
                this.getApplicationContext());
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            contentLog.append("Database Created\n");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        // Open the database
        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            contentLog.append("Database Opened\n");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get the readable version
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        contentLog.append("Get the readable database\n");

        // Make a select
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT libelle FROM detail_verbe ORDER BY libelle ASC;", null);

        cur.moveToPosition(0);
        Log.v(TAG, "Nb Col:" + cur.getColumnCount());
        Log.v(TAG, "Nb Records:" + cur.getCount());
        cur.close();
        contentLog.append("Select:\t" + cur.getColumnCount() + " cols, "
                + cur.getCount() + " rows\n");

        // Make an insert
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("libelle", "Serval");
        values.put("single_present", "Cat");
        long servalCatID = db.insert("detail_verbe", null, values);
        Log.v(TAG, "Serval Cat Inserted @: " + servalCatID);
        contentLog.append("Insert @ \t" + servalCatID + "\n");

        // Check insert
        cur = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT libelle FROM detail_verbe ORDER BY libelle ASC;", null);

        cur.moveToPosition(0);
        Log.v(TAG, "Nb Col:" + cur.getColumnCount());
        Log.v(TAG, "Nb Records:" + cur.getCount());
        cur.close();
        contentLog.append("Select:\t" + cur.getColumnCount() + " cols, "
                + cur.getCount() + " rows\n");

        // dumb
        cur = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT libelle FROM detail_verbe ORDER BY libelle ASC;",
                null);
        contentLog.append("\nDUMP\n");
        int i = 0;
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            contentLog.append("(" + i++ + ")\t\t" + cur.getString(0) + "\t"
                    + cur.getString(1) + "\n");
            cur.moveToNext();
        }

        cur.moveToPosition(0);

        // Close
        myDbHelper.close();
        contentLog.append("Database closed.");

        // YEAH
    }
```

This is the stacktrace

```
    02-19 15:19:07.265: V/ExtDB(8663): Nb Col:1 
02-19 15:19:07.269: V/ExtDB(8663): Nb Records:13 
02-19 15:19:07.308: V/ExtDB(8663): Serval Cat Inserted @: 14 
02-19 15:19:07.308: V/ExtDB(8663): Nb Col:1 
02-19 15:19:07.312: V/ExtDB(8663): Nb Records:14 
02-19 15:19:07.312: E/CursorWindow(8663): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 14 rows, 1 columns. 
02-19 15:19:07.320: D/AndroidRuntime(8663): Shutting down VM 02-19 15:19:07.320: W/dalvikvm(8663): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41856300) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.stackr.android.externaldb/fr.stackr.android.externaldb.ExternalDBActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at fr.stackr.android.externaldb.ExternalDBActivity.onCreate(ExternalDBActivity.java:88) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-19 15:19:07.363: E/AndroidRuntime(8663): ... 11 more
```

Comment: "but the existing one doesn't" -- this is an inadequate description of your symptoms. "I've posted picture of what the database looks like" -- where?

Comment: picture is in the link. and the .db file doesn't open in my app

Comment: some more information or some code would be nice. What das LogCat provide for error messages? How you try to create the database?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific, what do you imply by not working? Cursor not returning any values? How are you accessing it? Some code and logs could help

Comment: "and the .db file doesn't open in my app" -- this is an inadequate description of your symptoms.

Comment: And by not working I mean it crashes straight away.

Comment: 1 - Wrap the log inside a code format. 2 - Please post the snippet for the onCreate of class: ExternalDBActivity

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here:

```
cur.moveToPosition(0);
    Log.v(TAG, "Nb Col:" + cur.getColumnCount());
    Log.v(TAG, "Nb Records:" + cur.getCount());
    cur.close(); //cursor is closed
    //After closing, you call cur.get..() fix that
    contentLog.append("Select:\t" + cur.getColumnCount() + " cols, "
            + cur.getCount() + " rows\n");
```

If you will re-query (to check insert afterwards), there is no need to call close() there, until you know you are done with the cursor, maybe after closing the db would be a good choice.

Comment: I moved cur.close() to after myDBHelper.close(), but it still doesn't work. It just crashes.

Comment: There were two different places in the code where you call close(), did you fix both?

Comment: Yes I have, in both places.